# Navigate to sibling child router outlet not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

This is my routes component. Basically i'm routing the outlet to the html tabs

Currently I'm in Transactions page ->TransactionsComponent tab (single).

`<a [routerLink]="['../Product',{outlets :{ }}]"></a>`

I'm not sure what how should be the **routerlink** above to to navigate to the FridgeComponent -> 'fridge' outlet directly. I tried different option, none are working.

Please suggest the way to achieve this.

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',  redirectTo:'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent, 
      children:[
        {
            path :'', 
            component: HomeOneComponent, 
            outlet:'one'},
        {
            path :'', 
            component: HomeTwoComponent, 
            outlet:'two'
        }
  ]},
  { 
      path: 'Product',  
      component: ProductComponent, 
        children:[
            {path :'', component: TVComponent, outlet:'tv'},
            {path :'', component: ACComponent, outlet:'ac'},
            {path :'', component: FridgeComponent, outlet:'fridge'}
          ]

  },
  { 
      path: 'Transactions',  
      component: TransactionsComponent
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, you have to assign a value to the ***path*** in your routes, even for child routes.

```
.........  
{ 
  path: 'Product',  
  component: ProductComponent, 
    children:[
        {path :'tv', component: TVComponent, outlet:'tv'},
        {path :'ac', component: ACComponent, outlet:'ac'},
        {path :'fridge', component: FridgeComponent, outlet:'fridge'}
      ]

},
........
```

And in HTML ***routerLink***, make sure u mention the outlet name and path name

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/product', {outlets: {'fridge': ['fridge']}}]">                  
 </a>
```

If you still see the difficulty, please share in Github/plunker.

Comment: Providing the path value will work. But i dont want to display the path for each component. Since the children as part of the tabs. Is there a way without providing the path?